# html5 3 column layout problem

Tags: html, layout

I'm trying to convert my old html4 layout to a new html5 layout.

Is it wise to make a 3 column layout with the new css3 way or can i better use the old way ?

Roelof

Comment: It depends on what browsers you want to support?

Comment: I would like to make the site work on all browsers

Comment: CSS is not part of the HTML5 spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now only Mozilla and Webkit (Chrome, Safari) browsers support `multi-column` layouts.

IE, even up to 9, does not support this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#multicolumn

If you need to support IE, then you should consider:

1. coding with `div`s as columns or
2. coding with `multi-column` and using `conditional comments` to send different code to IE.

2 is a lot of work for not a lot of gain right now, in my opinion.

Comment: oke,thanks for the answers. I will use the old div layout then

Comment: Glad to help @roelof! Welcome to SO, btw.  If this answered your question, please consider accepting it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: IE always holds back the web.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [CSS3 Multi-Column Layout](http://www.thoughtresults.com/css-multicol), and implement it. However, it's not good for **general layout** of your entire web page. It's better for the layout of text inside a section or an article. Because it's main purpose is to imitate magazines and newspaper multi-column layout in texts.